SQL Validation Errors in Spring Tools 4.23.0
I've upgraded to Spring Tools for Eclipse 4.23.0 today and I have a quite annoying problem:
In my Spring Data Repository's SQL/HQL Queries I get errors for every named parameter (:parameterName Syntax).
It says "SQL: no viable alternative at input '...'"
Since those are marked as Errors my whole project is red and I can't find a way to disable those validations or reduce the severity to Warning or something like that.
Does someone have an idea how I can get rid of those errors?

This is a bug in the new query annotation validation that comes with Spring Tools for Eclipse 4.23.0:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1236#issuecomment-2166001442
Please update to the latest snapshot build (mentioned in the issue) or grab the latest snapshot distribution build from https://cdn.spring.io/spring-tools/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html where you get the preference to disable this.
